# calling a query from mysql table with php

Tags: php, mysql

i have this table of "score" below

```html
No   !  id   !  A      !  B    ! average  !
------------------------------------------
1    !  01   !  80     !  60   !    70    !
2    !  02   !         !  60   !    30    !
3    !  03   !  0      !  60   !    30    !
4    !  04   !  80     !       !    40    !
```

i want to call column "average" using this code below

```html
$mySql = "SELECT score.id, (SUM(COALESCE(A,0)) + SUM(COALESCE(B,0))) / (COUNT(A) + COUNT(B)) FROM score GROUP by id"; 
 $myQry = mysql_query($mySql, $koneksidb)  or die ("Query salah : ".mysql_error());
 $myData = mysql_fetch_array($myQry);
```

with php to call i use:

```html
<?php echo $myData; ?>
```

but it came out empty like this:

```html
!  average    !
-----------
!            !
!            ! 
!            !
!            !
```

what did i do wrong?

i changed it into

```html
$mySql="SELECT id, AVG(COALESCE(A, 0) + COALESCE(B, 0)) AS average FROM score GROUP by id"; 
$myQry = mysql_query($mySql, $koneksidb) or die ("Query salah : ".mysql_error()); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($myQry)) { echo $row['average']; }
```

still cant work, i have put php inside the while loop, it came out the same number now

Comment: mysql_ deprecated try to use mysqli or PDO

Comment: @gtviga you should add comments to your query and edit your question as right now it is not clear.

Comment: Fetching will convert it to an array style format (although not iterative so you can't use a for loop). You want to use a while loop not just `echo $myData`: `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($myQry)) {
    echo $row['average'];
}`

Comment: i wrote

$mySql="SELECT led7ape.led7ape_id, AVG(COALESCE(led7apet1h, 0) + COALESCE(led7apet2h, 0)) AS average
FROM led7ape GROUP by led7ape_id";
$myQry = mysql_query($mySql, $koneksidb)  or die ("Query salah : ".mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($myQry)) { echo $row['average']; }

when i write
<?php echo $row['average']; ?>
it came out empty

Comment: the echo inside the while loop should echo out the table contents. if you try to echo outside of the while loop then `$row` won't exist.

Comment: Also edit the code in your question as it is difficult to read code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

There is should be used an `AVG()` grouping function:

```
SELECT led7ape.led7ape_id,
  AVG(COALESCE(led7apet1h, 0) + COALESCE(led7apet2h, 0)) AS `average`
  FROM led7ape GROUP by led7ape_id
```

And if there is nothing to group indeed (each row has unique id here), just sum two fields as follows:

```
SELECT led7ape.led7ape_id,
  COALESCE(led7apet1h, 0) + COALESCE(led7apet2h, 0)) AS `average`
  FROM led7ape
```

Comment: i wrote

$mySql="SELECT led7ape.led7ape_id, AVG(COALESCE(led7apet1h, 0) + COALESCE(led7apet2h, 0)) AS average
FROM led7ape GROUP by led7ape_id";
$myQry = mysql_query($mySql, $koneksidb)  or die ("Query salah : ".mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($myQry)) { echo $row['average']; }

when i write
<?php echo $row['average']; ?>
it came out empty